# Phrases update query

Tags: strings, sql, mysql

My query is this:

```
UPDATE `phrases`
SET `phrases`.`count`=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `strings` WHERE `string` LIKE CONCAT('%', `phrases`.`phrase`, '%'))
```

My tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `phrases` (
    `hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    `count` int DEFAULT 0,
    `phrase` text NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`hash`),
     KEY(`count`)
)
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE `strings` (
    `string` text NOT NULL,
)
```

`phrases` has 18,000 rows and `strings` has 1500 rows.

Comment: It might be more efficient to have a separate table where you would store the counts per phrase, and then only update this table once a new string is added. Since the number of strings is low in comparison to the phrases, I figure this wont happen that often. So you would not perform the whole count again, just add 1 if the new string matches that phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using a `LIKE` with wildcards, you're going to do a table-scan against both tables, running a total of 18000*1500 = 27000000 substring comparisons.

To optimize this, you need to use some fulltext index technology.  I suggest [Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [Apache Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/).  If you do this, you don't need to keep a count of how many matches there are, because the search index makes it a lot less expensive to get a count on demand.

MySQL also implements a [FULLTEXT index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html) type, but it is only supported in the MyISAM storage engine in current versions (up to 5.5).  I don't recommend using MyISAM for important data.

MySQL 5.6 is developing a fulltext index for InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

You should drop the index and collect the counts.

This will speed up the updating of the `count` column.

When done, put the index back.

```
ALTER TABLE phrase DROP INDEX `count`;
UPDATE phrase SET COUNT=0;
UPDATE phrases INNER JOIN string
ON ( LOCATE(strings.string,phrases.phrase) > 0 )
SET phrase.`count`=phrase.`count`+1;
ALTER TABLE phrase ADD INDEX `count` (`count`);
```

This INNER JOIN is nothing more than a Cartesian Product (pointed out by Bill Karwin's answer as 27,000,000 rows being examined in a temp table).

If the time to process is something can live with, all well and good.

If the time to process is disastrously slow, *you must try Bill Karwin's answer*.